# Does Falcon 9 perform static fires before every launch?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse, launch-vehicle

Before launching every Falcon 9 rocket, is SpaceX performing a Wet Dress Rehearshal (WDR) and a static fire?

If not before every launch then is it doing it before every first launch of a new booster?

Same question for the second stage.

Related question:

- [What work needs to be done before reusing Falcon 9?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16595/what-work-needs-to-be-done-before-reusing-falcon-9)

Answer (score 4):

Initially they did a WDR and hot fire test before each launch.

They have begun to skip some of these steps of late. Mostly on Starlink missions since they are the customer, they are building 4400 of these satellites and if something goes wrong the cost is not high.

There has yet to be a clear pattern evolve, but it is early in the process and it may become clearer in time.

The main pattern is important customers get a static fire before launch..

Comment: How about Wet Dress Rehearshal?

Comment: "if something goes wrong the cost is not high": also, the sort of thing that would get caught by a static fire would just abort the launch before liftoff, leading to a delay.  For Starlink, it's a very minor issue to just choose to fill another set of orbits or wait for the next opening for their original destination. What's a minor inconvenience for Starlink launches might be a major issue for other launches due to limited launch windows or other considerations.